# How to remove GRUB after deleting Ubuntu and repair Windows MBR

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I tried to delete Ubuntu by doing what was found online:  Delete the partitions, then do an advanced startup into Command prompt to fix the MBR.  Oops, instead of the old GRUB Menu that comes up, allowing me to select Windows with the down arrow, it brings up GRUB command line. I am able to boot Windows by typing `exit` - this brings up the firmware settings allowing me to select Windows. But Ubuntu is still in the list, even though I deleted it.

What I want to do it get rid of GRUB so Windows can boot normally.

I have an Ubuntu installation disk but whenever I try to boot from it if brings up a unhelpful command prompt - initrampfs or something along those lines.

Also, I don't have a Windows Installation Disk.

Comment: Do you mean you tried to delete Ubuntu? (second sentence)

Comment: Yes, I did delete it, so the only thing that remains of Ubuntu is GRUB (see Edit).

Comment: I've seen your edit, but your second sentence still says "I tried to delete windows"

Comment: Oops, my bad, i see what you mean.  Gone are the days when I still had my wits about me.

Comment: Haha I know the feeling :) but reading the edit your question is confusing - you can boot windows and just want to delete GRUB in a way that allows you to boot windows. Does your computer boot in UEFI mode?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by UEFI mode.  What happens is, when I turn the computer on, it brings up GRUB.  I enter exit and it says "Ubuntu booted successfully".  Then it brings up a menu (a blue and Grey menu - like the firmware settings) that allows me to select an OS.  What I am really trying to do is reset my PC to its factory default (i.e. the boot part of it)

Comment: maybe [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/422023/527764) or the one above... There are lots of questions like yours and this is probably the canonical one

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of it by installing MBR new on the booted Windows.
For example this could work: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html
(untested cause I love ubuntu :-)